# upload files in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I am just a beginner in php and I am trying to run the next code for upload a file in a local server, but it is not possible.  What is wrong? Thanks.

Code 1 (form):

```
    <head>
<title>PHP</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor = "#303030">
<body text = "#FFFFFF">
<body leftmargin = "60">
<body topmargin = "60">
<font face = "Tahoma">
<font size = "3">
<form enctype = "multipart/form-data" action = "upload.php" method = "post">
        <input type = "hidden" name = "lim_size" value = "500000">
        <font size = "6"><b>Upload form:</b></font size>
        <p>
        <b>File to transfer</b>
        <br>
        <input type = "file" name = "file">
        </p>
        <p>
        <input type = "submit" name = "send" value = "Accept">
        </p>
</form>
</head>
<b>Choose file and push button</b>
```

Code 2:

```
<title>PHP</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor = "#303030">
<body text = "#FFFFFF">
<body leftmargin = "60">
<body topmargin = "60">
<font face = "Tahoma">
<font size = "3">

<?php
if($file != "none" AND $file_size != 0 AND $file_size <= $lim_size) {
        if (copy($file, "/opt/lampp/temp/".$file_name)){
                echo "<h2>file transfered $file_name</h2>";
                echo "<br>File size: $file_size bytes<br>";
                echo "<br>File type: $file_type<br>";
                }
        }else{
                echo "<h2>Error</h2>";
                echo "<h2>Error</h2>";
        }
echo "<a href= '.$file_name.'>";
?>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does "it is not possible" mean? What happened when you tried to run it? Did you get an error message? Be as specific as you can.

Comment: i reccomend you check https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: also from what I can see you are not ready yet please try and learn the basics of php and php variables before you try and do complicated stuff like file upload i recommend you watch dani krossing on youtube he is really great teacher https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVU3V0A05k8&list=PL0eyrZgxdwhwBToawjm9faF1ixePexft-

Comment: I can explain to you what you did wrong but it will be very long and complex so i think it will be better for you to learn from a series of vids